# Valor de resultado indica cuantos registros te tiene que devolver la consulta del left join SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola buen dia quiero hacer la siguiente pregunta quiero el valor de resultado va a indicar cuantos registros te tiene que devolver la consulta del left join tengo la consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT '001' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV1' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '001' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV2' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '001' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV3' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '001' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV4' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '001' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV5' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '001' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV6' AS MOV) 
MOVIMIENTOS 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  TABLA.CLAVE,(TABLA.A-TABLA.B) AS RESULTADO 
    FROM 
    (SELECT '001' AS CLAVE, 10 AS A ,8 AS B) TABLA
) TB1 ON TB1.CLAVE=MOVIMIENTOS.CLAVE2
```

y me trae el siguiente resultado:

```
001 MOV1    001 2
001 MOV2    001 2
001 MOV3    001 2
001 MOV4    001 2
001 MOV5    001 2
001 MOV6    001 2
```

si se fijan en el left join el resultado es 2 entonces de acuerdo a ese resultado quiero que traiga los movimientos quedando de la siquiente forma:

```
001 MOV1    001 2
001 MOV2    001 2
```

espero si me pueden ayudar por favor

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY CLAVE ORDER BY CLAVE) AS X   FROM (
    SELECT '001' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV1' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '001' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV2' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '001' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV3' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '001' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV4' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '001' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV5' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '001' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV6' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV7' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV8' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV9' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV10' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV11' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV12' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV13' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV14' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV15' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV16' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV17' AS MOV
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE2, 'MOV18' AS MOV) 
MOVIMIENTOS 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  TABLA.CLAVE,(TABLA.A-TABLA.B) AS RESULTADO
    FROM 
    (SELECT '001' AS CLAVE, 10 AS A ,6 AS B UNION ALL
    SELECT '002' AS CLAVE, 5 AS A ,0 AS B ) TABLA
) TB1 ON TB1.CLAVE=MOVIMIENTOS.CLAVE2 
) test where X<=RESULTADO ORDER BY CLAVE2
```

lo resolvi haciendo la consulta como arriba si alguien le sirve adelante si tiene mejoras bienvenidas